# Iphone X eats up ram while iphone 7 works properly on angular app on page with intersectionObserver

Tags: iphone, angular, intersection-observer

Same website subpage. RAM usage difference between iphone X and iphone 7 over 10 times. (X about 900MB, 7 about 90MB).
When i load a route of my angular 6 app where i use IntersectionObserver to lazy load some images, RAM just explode on X and after using the page for a few minutes it crash (safari not responding, chrome show 'oh snap' page. iOS 12.3 on both devices.
Does anybody knows what can cause the issue.